# Run high computation task in async with feedback

Tags: java, spring, microservices, quartz-scheduler

I am using spring for out web application. One API does a lot of computation which looks like this.

```
void serviceMethod(){
   fetchFromDB();
   veryLongComputation1();  //1
   veryLongComputation2();  //2
   veryLongComputation3();  //3 
}
```

My API takes a lot of time to run. Steps 1,2 and 3 takes lot of time because they have lot of computation and lot of IO (to db) too.

What I want is to return the response and run the 1,2,3 in a thread. But problem with that approach is if my application crashes, this code will never be executed.

Can someone suggest some approaches to encounter this problem? One thing to remember, there will be many instances of the application.

Comment: Ideally, reactive programming is best suited for such use cases. Spring provides reactor framework with `Flux` and `Mono` to help you with such tasks, There are various schedulers available.

Answer (score 0):

Java provides an [async servlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm) to handle requests which takes long time to complete. The basic idea is Http thread in the servlet container triggers the computation and returns immediately whereas the response is sent only when the computation is complete. See the sample below

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/asyncservlet"}, asyncSupported=true)
public class AsyncServlet extends HttpServlet {
   /* ... Same variables and init method as in SyncServlet ... */

   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                     HttpServletResponse response) {
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      final AsyncContext acontext = request.startAsync();
      acontext.start(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            String param = acontext.getRequest().getParameter("param");
            String result = resource.process(param);
            HttpServletResponse response = acontext.getResponse();
            /* ... print to the response ... */
            acontext.complete();
   }
}
```

The same thing in [spring](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-spring-reactive-servlet-async)

```
@GetMapping(value = "/asyncNonBlockingRequestProcessing")

    public CompletableFuture<String> asyncNonBlockingRequestProcessing(){

            ListenableFuture<String> listenableFuture = getRequest.execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<String>() {

                @Override

                public String onCompleted(Response response) throws Exception {

                    logger.debug("Async Non Blocking Request processing completed");

                    return "Async Non blocking...";

                }

            });

            return listenableFuture.toCompletableFuture();

    }
```

Comment: But again, the client will wait until the request is completed. I want to run these tasks in background.

Comment: Then you can just delegate it to a thread pool and return the response as task-id. You can have another endpoint for monitoring the completion status of the task by id.

Comment: What if the application fails in b/w. I will loose all the progress. It should be done completely.